# Removing characters from objects inside a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having some trouble removing the double quotes character from my data.  I know this question gets asked a lot but I cant find an answer that helps...

I have an array of data which contains objects.  Each object has strings that look like this (taken from Chrome DevTools):

```
0: Object
coID: 1
country: "ireland"
email: "email"
history: "history line 1<br>history line 2<br>history line 3<br>history line 4"
name: "My Company"
phone: "0872780000"

1: Object
coID: 2
country: ""ireland""
email: ""email@mail.com""
history: ""history line 1"<br>"history line 2"<br>"history line 3"<br>"history line 4""
name: ""Other Company""
phone: ""0872780000""
```

As you see the second object has double quotes all over the place.  To remove them, I tried this:

```
// replace any instances of the quotes character.
for(m=0; m<listOfCompanies.length; m++) { 
    for(n=0; n<listOfCompanies[m].length; n++) {
        dataIn[m][n].replace(/\"/g,'');
    }
}
```

It doesn't do anything though, and the quotes remain intact in the second object.

And also this (from Matt S):

```
// replace any instances of the quotes character.
for(m=0; m<listOfCompanies.length; m++) { 
    for(n=0; n<listOfCompanies[m].length; n++) {
        dataIn[m][n] = dataIn[m][n].replace(/\"/g,'');
    }
}
```

Am I able to use this method for this type of data? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replace` returns the updated string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).  It doesn't replace inline.  So,

```
dataIn[m][n] = dataIn[m][n].replace(/\"/g,'');
```

Comment: Replacing dataIn[m][n].replace(/\"/g,''); with your code also does nothing??

Comment: Alright, well this doesn't work but only because made a boo boo. Actual should be dataIn[m].phone = dataIn[m].phone.replace(/\"/g,'');